# Delete file with past date in name in PHP

Tags: php, events, date, file, flat

I have an event manager i am making, thats almost done, but one thing. I have a file, `view.php` that view the events. however, i need to delete events that have dates in the past.

it is flat file, so the dates are stores as file names, in the folder `data`. their names would be dates. for instance: `"data/Monday, 21 February, 2011.html"` would be for that date. does anybody have any ideas on how to delete events (files) that are in the past?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could look at the file's creation date/time using `stat()` and decide based on that. Otherwise you're stuck generating every possible past date and trying to `unlink()` each in turn. Shouldn't this be in a database? Then it'd be a simple `DELETE ... WHERE date < now()` type thing.

Comment: I cant get the creation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a rod for your back with this naming scheme (it's also generally bad practice to have files with spaces in as far as possible), but no matter.

What you need to do is:

1. Scan the target directory using [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) or similar. ([glob](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) might be a better bet depending on the contents of the directory.)
2. Convert each valid (i.e.: not "." or "..") html file name into a timestamp via [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) after using [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to get rid of the ".html" portion.
3. [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the file if it's in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Or, a better option would be to store a numeric timestamp instead of the text format. Then you could delete the necessary files with something like:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/your/files');
foreach($dir as $file) {
    ... extract timestamp from each file ...
    ... if it's less than your cutoff, delete file ...
}
```

That'd save you the trouble of having to parse the date part of the filename into a datetime value each time, and you're down to a simple numeric comparison.